# How to perform sql operation to insert data into a second table based on primary key matching to another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry if the title is not clear. Basically I'm trying to achieve the following:

A very simple example. I have two tables with two columns each

Table 1:

```
Name: Fred, David, Alex, Jim, Mike

Chocolates: 1, 5, 3, 2, 4
```

Table 2:

```
Name: Fred, David, Alex, Jim, Mike

Lollipops:
```

Say I want to fill the Lollipops columns so that each person has ONE more lollipop than they have chocolates. i.e. `Lollipops: 2, 6, 4, 3, 5`. Where Name is a primary key in both tables. How to achieve this using sql query and java servlets please? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query:

```
update table2 t2
join table1 t1 on t2.Name = t1.Name
set t2.Lollipops = t1.Chocolates + 1
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4b4c7/1)

Comment: @javaprogrammer `t2` is just an alias used for brevity.